# SQL get the 5 last items inserted based on 2 table join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, project/images related:

```
[project]
project_id (int primary key)
completed (date)

[project_media]
project_media_id (int primary key)
project_id (int foreign key)
image (varchar)
```

What I want to select is:
from the last 5 project records based on completed, take the last image added based on project_media_id.

In other words the last image inserted from the last 5 projects.

What I have so far:

```
select project.completed, project_media.project_id, project_media.image 
from project 
inner join project_media 
    on project.project_id = project_media.project_id 
order by completed desc limit 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT PR.*, 
(
  SELECT PM.image FROM project_media PM
  WHERE PR.project_id = PM.project_id
  ORDER BY PM.project_media_id DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS image
FROM 
(
  SELECT P.project_id, P.completed 
  FROM project P
  ORDER BY P.completed DESC
  LIMIT 5
) AS PR
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to just get the five most recent things in the project table, you'd do this:

```
select * from project order by completed desc limit 5;
```

Joining in the other table, you'd end up with something like this:

```
select * from project p join project_media pm on p.project_id = pm.project_id order by completed desc limit 5;
```

Limiting the columns, your query will be:

```
select pm.image from project p join project_media pm on p.project_id = pm.project_id order by completed desc limit 5;
```

I'm a little unclear about what you're asking in the last bit, but it sounds like what you now want to get only one image based on the media_project_id, from these five things.  You could do this with a subquery:

```
select a.image from (select pm.image, pm.project_media_id from project p join project_media pm on p.project_id = pm.project_id order by completed desc limit 5) a order by a.project_media_id limit 1;
```

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PM2.image
FROM
(
  SELECT
      P.project_id,
      MAX(PM.project_media_id) AS last_project_media
  FROM project_media PM
    JOIN project P ON P.project_id = PM.project_id
  GROUP BY PM.project_id
  ORDER BY PM.completed DESC
  LIMIT 5
) PM1
JOIN project_media PM2
    ON PM1.last_project_media = PM2.project_media_id
```